# gmap3: How to get denied localisation event?

Tags: jquery, geolocation, google-maps

I'm using the getgeoloc of gmap3.js (jQuery plugin)
http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/14-services/getgeoloc-54

```
$('#test1').gmap3({
    getgeoloc:{
      callback : function(latLng){
        if (latLng){
          $(this).gmap3({
            marker:{ latLng:latLng }
          });
        }else{
          alert('browser didn't find the position.');
        }
      }
    }   
});
```

If the user denied the geolocalisation from the browser.
how can I get that event?

the "else" of "if (latLng)" is only in case the browser can not find the user position. but if the user clicks "denied location"?

Has someone the same problem?

Comment: Solved. The problem was only on the local server with chrome. Online it works fine with if{}else{}.

Comment: You should post your own answer and accept the answer. Furthermore this belongs on stack overflow not webmasters.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
The problem was only on the local server with chrome. Online it works fine with if{}else{}